# How to monitor/log internet up time

Tags: connections

I have home network setup, where I have 1 thomson wifi router, 2 telephones, 1 tv, 1 desktop and 4+ laptops. I have the Estonian standard internet of ~15 Mbps for the last 4+ few years. The desktop system is live 24/7 and goes down only for windows updates, so I will be using it to monitor the network. It has Win 7 Pro (64 bit), but I assume, that I can run Linux apps/utils on cigwin.

Time to time internet is dropping. **I want to know statistics like: when, how long, etc.** I am planning to run the tests for 1 week or so. It would be great if log is smaller then 4gb and I don't need regex to parse it (and program would not crash).

I assume (with 95% confidence) problem is ISPs fault (or 5% weird anomalies in weather or cables), so it would be great if I could create a presentable report, that can be used to fix the problem. Hidden question here is, what information should it contain.

This is a home network, so I'm not thrilled in idea of buying expensive software for it. Sorry for asking a question, where there exists more then 1 correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can only reply from Linux and opensource world.

Nagios, Xymon, Zabbix, mon are all good monitoring open source softwares that can achieve what you want ( stats, graphs, history, uptime ).

If you don't want to reinstall with linux, you can simply launch a linux distribution via Oracle VirtualBox all for free.

Answer (score 0):

The Net Uptime Monitor - http://www.netuptimemonitor.com - is exactly what you want.  I wrote this program to diagnose an intermittent connection that bugged me for three years!

It's a simple Windows program that continuously tests your internet connection and writes a plain text log with the start time and length of each connection failure.  No complex setup - just install and run to track every time your connection goes down!

Comment: The OP has clearly stated that he is not interested in paid software and $9.95 is clearly expensive for something so basic and easy to do. I would -1 twice if I could for plugging your own paid software in violation for what was asked for.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way.  Everyone is not a programmer and building a proper app with logging and easily configured settings is not a $10 job for anyone.  OP said he's not interested in "expensive" software.  I don't think most people consider $10 to be expensive.  As far as "violation", my post was cleared by the moderators after lengthy review as a legitimate response to the question asked.  It's not unrelated spam about working from home!

Comment: I take your point about expensive being relative. I guess it should have been qualified ($10 not being expensive for most people has a clear first world bias). If the moderators cleared it, great.